# Need help understanding Python Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, bit

Please help in understanding the logic behind the following function:

```
def bit_rev (x, b): # reverse b lower bits of x
    return sum (1<<(b-1-i) for i in range (0, b) if (x>>i) & 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the code and it doesn't seem to account for bits past the b'th bit.  So, I added another addition. (Unless all you want is up to the b'th bit):

```
def bit_rev (x, b): # reverse b lower bits of x
    return (x >> b << b) + sum(1 << (b - 1 - i) for i in range (0, b) if (x >> i) & 1)
```

Now for the explaining the logic.

`x >> b << b`

So, let's say we're using 5 (as `x`) in this example with 2 as `b`.

The binary representation of 5 is `101`.  So, we want to switch only the last 2 bits.  Which is `01`.  However, in our other code we are swapping them, but we are ignoring the bits past b.  So, we are ignoring the first (from left to right) `1`.

Now the first operations:

1. `x >> b` in our case is `5 >> 2`. 101 moving to the right 2 is `1`, since we end up chopping off the `01`.
2. Next we shift it back.  We are guaranteed (in Python) to get 0's back from the bit shift, so we now have `100`, or 4.

Now for the meaty part,

```
sum(1 << (b - 1 - i) for i in range (0, b) if (x >> i) & 1)
```

It's probably would be easier to understand this outside of a list comprehension, so I rewrote it as a for-loop.

```
summation = 0
for i in range (0, b):
    if (x >> i) & 1:
        summation += 1 << (b - 1 - i)
```

Basically on each iteration we are finding the reverse bit an then adding it to the total (`summation`).

This code seems to be kind of difficult to understand because there is a lot going on.

Let's start with the for loop itself.  `for i in range (0, b)` is iterating over all values between 0 and b. (Or the last bit you want to change). All the reversing happens later on in the code.

Next we check to see if the bit we are going to swap is a `1`.  In binary only `1`'s add value to the total number, so its logical to ignore all `0`'s.  In `if (x >> i) & 1:`.  We bitshift x to the right i bits.  So, `101` bit shifted to the right 1 bit is `10`.  We now check to see if that last bit is a 1 by doing `& 1`.  Basically what `& 1` does in this program is ignore all bits beyond the first bit.

The and bitwise operator works as follows:

```
 0101
&1100
=0100
```

And requires both to be true. Since all bits past `1` would be 0, it effectively ignores the rest.

Now we get a 0 or a 1 from `(x >> i) & 1` and Python processes all non-zero integers as True and zero as False.  This will make use ignore all bits that are zero.

Next, we add to summation using: `summation += 1 << (b - 1 - i)`.  We get the location of where it the bit is going to be by using `b - 1 - i`.  Then we shift 1 over to that location and then add it to the total.

When adding two binary integers, you can add a 1 to a location in the number similar to how you would base 10.  So, if I had the number 9000 and I wanted a 1 in the hundredths digit I could do 9000 + 100.  That is similar to what we are doing here.  We are moving it over to the left in base 2 by using the `<<` operator instead of taking 10^i.  So we are setting the newly reversed bit to whatever the original bit was.

Comment: Thank you so much, @neil. This makes it easier to grasp the workings of the bit function. Can you let me know why my question was downvoted? Did I commit a crime by asking one here?